# How to find non-existing records?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 Tables

Table 1 is a Trainings Table:

| TrainingID | Name | Someotherfield |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | whatever is |
| 2 | bb | in this field |

Table 2 is an employee list

| EmpID | LastName | FirstName | DOB | etc. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe | mm |  |
| 2 | Jane | Foe | yy |  |

Table 3 is the table where these two tables meet :

| EmpID | TrainingID | Compdate | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | ddmmyy | x |
| 2 | 1 | ddmmyy | x |
| 2 | 2 | ddmmyy | x |
| 2 | 3 | ddmmyy | x |

What I need to be able to do, is query these three tables and return an EmpID and a TrainingID that are both not in the third table, so in this example my ideal response would be :

| EmpID | TrainingID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

What I have managed to do so far, is not great:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CompletedTrainings
LEFT JOIN Trainings ON Trainings.TrainingID = CompletedTrainings.Training
WHERE ISNULL ( Trainings.TrainingID
```

This returns a list of employees, but not the training numbers that are missing.

I have tried a variant of this using NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT CompletedTrainings.Employee, CompletedTrainings.Training
FROM CompletedTrainings
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT TrainingID, [Training Name]
FROM Trainings
WHERE Trainings.TrainingID = CompletedTrainings.Training);
```

This again returns a list of employee names, but not the names of the missing trainings.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cross join (via `,`) in MS Access and then `not exists` or `left join`:

```
select t.*, e.*
from trainings as t,
     employees as e
where not exists (select 1
                  from employeeTrainings as et
                  where et.EmpID = e.EmpID and et.trainingID = t.trainingID
                 );
```

Comment: This works, at least as far as the requested information goes, but it is now asking for a Parameter entry "Query 1.FirstName" ... Which is odd, because I don't think it did that the first time I ran it.

Comment: I reversed the order of the two tables and the Parameter Request went away.

Comment: @ChristopherJ.Joubert . . . That is odd.  And, there is no reference to `FirstName` in the query.  Glad it got fixed!